# How to inherit privately from a base class' derivative, but implement public interface of the base class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, encapsulation

Suppose there are two unchangeable classes from a library, `A` and `B`, related like here:

```
class A
{
public:
    virtual void doCustomThings() = 0;
    virtual void doOtherThings() = 0;
    void doSomething();
private:
    SomeType1 someData;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void doCustomThings() override;
    void doOtherThings() override;
    void someUsefulUtility();
private:
    SomeType2 otherData;
};
```

I'm trying to implement the interface of `A` in terms of the some available in `B`, so I do:

```
class C : public B
{
public:
    void doCustomThings() override; // uses B::someUsefulUtility()
    // leave B::doOtherThings() not overridden
private:
    SomeType3 myData;
};
```

But I don't intend `C` to *be* `B`, i.e. I don't want references to `C` to be implicitly convertible to `B&`, although it should be convertible to `A&`.

First thing coming to mind is to use virtual inheritance, and then inherit `public A, private B`. But the `A` and `B` classes in my case are not editable, and for virtual inheritance to work here I need `class B` to inherit as `public virtual A`.

Another idea is to consider composition instead of inheritance. But if I derive from `A` and have `B` as a private member, I'll uselessly have `A::someData` twice, which looks inelegant.

Is there any good way to so something like `class C : public A, private B`, so that there'd be only one base class `A`, given the above mentioned constraints?

Comment: _But I don't intend C to be B_ <-- Do you want C to be A?

Comment: @skypjack yes, I want `C` to implement `A`'s virtual methods.

Comment: Since B is an A, why does it matter if C converts to B?  It will also be convertible to A, since B is an A.

Comment: @ttemple because `B` has some extra functionality I don't want to expose in `C`.

Comment: make C inherit from A, move implementation of B into separate h and cpp, include and use this implementation in both B.cpp and C.cpp

Comment: @AndrewKashpur as I've mentioned, `A` and `B` are unchangeable. They are from a read-only library.

Comment: If you don't intend C to be B but you want it to be A then the only way I can think of is to inherit A and override the methods. That is more natural than trying to Publicly inherit A and compose B inside C. You can copy the necessary implementation from B and use it in C (B is readable). May be you want to avoid code duplication which is why you have asked this question but given the scenarios this seems better to me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use private inheritance and exposed the desired members with `using`.

```
class C : private B
{
public:
    using B::A;// to make it convertible to A
    using B::doOtherThings;

    void doCustomThings() override {
        std::cout<<"C::doCustomThings()\n";    
    }
private:
    char myData;
};
```

[Working example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6bf7bffb8e9f898d).

Comment: `C&` is then not convertible to `A&`: e.g. `A& ac=c;` added to your working example doesn't compile.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, only use inheritance for `A`, use composition for `B`, and delegate to the `B` member (not base)

```
class C : public A
{
public:
    void doOtherThings() override { myB.doOtherThings(); }

    void doCustomThings() override {
        std::cout<<"C::doCustomThings()\n";    
    }
private:
    B myB;
    SomeType3 myData;
};
```

Comment: How does this solve the duplicated `A::someData` problem?

Comment: Either you can safely ignore it, or **whichever** scheme you choose **can't** behave correctly in all cases